# How can I combine arrays in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following:

```
[[1, 2], [3], [4,5], [6,1], [5,3,4], [4,7]]
```

I'm trying to combine these so that if a number is in another array, I combine the arrays.  The output should be this:

```
[[1,2,6],[3,4,5,7]]
```

Any ideas on how I can do this in Python?

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this? What did you try?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "if the number is in another array". If what number is in another array?

Comment: What is the rule for your array combination?

Comment: @merlin2011, I think its if two of the sublists share a common number, the should be combined

Comment: Does the output have to be sorted? Also it looks like you want to remove duplicates. You can use sets instead.

Comment: @wnnmaw, yes that's right.

Comment: @crclayton - yes that's what I'm looking for.  Sorry for the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

```
>>> L = [[1, 2], [3], [4,5], [6,1], [5,3,4], [4,7]]
>>> L = [set(e) for e in L]
>>> combined = []
>>> while L:
...     group = L.pop()
...     for other in L:
...         if group.intersection(other):
...             group.update(other)
...     L = [e for e in L if not group.intersection(e)]
...     combined.append(group)
... 
>>> combined
[set([3, 4, 5, 7]), set([1, 2, 6])]
```

This first converts each group in the original list to set, then greedily merges the elements together into groups.

Comment: Just about to post this, but you beat me to it.